# Make an Image child of multiple stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a custom file picker. For that I require one Image object to be used by multiple folder which I have displayed as a StackPanel.

```
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("I:/image.jpg"));

foreach(string s in Directory.GetDirectories("I:/"))
{
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
sp.Children.Add(image);
sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock{Text = s,});
}
```

This throws an InvalidOperationException since i cannot add single instance of an Image to multiple StackPanel.
Any help ?

Comment: You can't. Please clarify what requirements are optional so someone can answer

Comment: It seems redundant to me to create an Image for every folder Icon.
Maybe I can can derive a control from StackPanel create an Image & Textblock instance in that. But then will that render ?

Answer (score 0):

Reuse the BitmapImage:

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("I:/image.jpg"));

foreach (string s in Directory.GetDirectories("I:/"))
{
    var sp = new StackPanel();
    sp.Children.Add(new Image { Source = bitmap });
    sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = s });
}
```

---

Besides that, if you are going to add multiple similar items to a parent control, consider using an ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="I:\image.jpg"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

and fill it like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"I:\");
}
```